# Platform Agnostic Means to Detect Computer Went to Sleep?

Tags: shell, sh

Quite simply I have a shell script with some long-running operations that I run in the background and then wait for in a loop (so I can check if they're taking too long, report progress etc.).

However one case that I'd also like to check for is when the system has been put to sleep manually (I've already taken steps to ensure it shouldn't auto-sleep while my script is running).

Currently I do this in a fairly horrible way, namely my script runs `sleep` in a loop for a few seconds at a time, checking each time if the task is still running. To detect sleep I check if the time elapsed was longer than expected, like so:

```
start=$(date +%s)
while sleep 5; do
    if [ $(($(date +%s) - $start)) -gt 6 ]; then
        echo 'System may have been asleep'
        start=$(date +%s)
    elif kill -0 $PID; then
        echo 'Task is still running'
        start=$(date +%s)
    else
        echo 'Task is complete'
        break
    fi
done
```

The above is very much simplified so please forgive any mistakes, it's just to give the basic idea; for example, on platforms where the `wait` command supports timeouts I already use that in place of `sleep`.

Now, while this mostly works, it's not especially pretty and it's not really detecting sleep, but guessing whether the system **might** have slept; for example, it can't differentiate cases where a system hangs long enough to confound the check, making the check time longer will help with this, but it's still guesswork.

On macOS I can more reliably check for sleep using `pmset -g uuid` which returns a new UUID if the system went to sleep. What I would like to know is, are there any alternatives for other platforms?

In essence all I need is a way to find out if the system has been asleep since the last time I checked, though if there's a way to receive a signal or such instead then that may be even better.

While I'm looking to hear of the best options available on various platforms, I crucially need a shell agnostic option as well that I can use as a reliable fallback, as I'd still like the shell script to be as portable as possible.

Comment: `if [ $(($(date +%s) - $start)) -gt 6 ]]` - just `if (( $(date +%s) - start > 6 )); then`. `on various platforms` - I believe it's impossible to do it "platform agnostic", you can just target multiple platforms and handle is separately. What platforms do you want to target? `are there any alternatives for other platforms?` - Each platform may or may not provide an interface for that. I think you should create questions for each platform and ask how to detect sleep on such and such platform. Your question is tagged with `shell` and `sh` - "detecting sleep" is outside of posix shell scope.

Comment: @KamilCuk: I don't require an exhaustive list, a selection of common options is fine. If my current code is about as good as I can except, then that's fine too, as I can always use that as the fallback if I must, but is it the best/simplest fallback option? Are there others? `shell`/`sh` has access to a variety of tools through a variety of platforms, so it's not out of scope for the most common to be suggested.

Comment: On linux interest yourself with systemd-suspend.service or acpid with /etc/pm/sleep.d . `a variety of platforms, so it's not out of scope for the most common` - but the problem is, I am not inclined to tell you what is the most common solution. And still "various platforms" is too broad. Are you interested in solaris? Windows? AIX? Minix? OpenBSD? Android? "sh has access to variety of tools" - but that doesn't mean that those _will_ be available on a particular platform. And, as this is tagged with `sh` and `shell` - so you mean a platform with POSIX shell - detecting sleep is outside of `sh`

Comment: @KamilCuk: Thank you for referring to `systemd-suspend.service` and `sleep.d` at least, but I have to say I'm not liking this attitude. I've already shown `sh` is capable of detecting if a system went to sleep, and am looking for improvements. You seem to have some bizarre idea of what `sh` is; it is a means of interfacing with any platform that can execute `sh` scripts, so everything `sh` can access is within scope. My script already has a bunch of platform-specific improvements, with strict POSIX fallbacks as appropriate, it's how every good `sh` script should be written.